# How to swap items in a list?

Tags: java, arraylist, swap

I've been trying to figure out how to swap items in an arraylist; so first I created an arraylist using this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListADT {
public static void main (String[] args){
    List <String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); {
    myList.add("A");
    myList.add("B");
    myList.add("C");
    myList.add("D");
    myList.add("E");
System.out.println(myList);}}}
```

This returns [A,B,C,D,E] on the console.
Then I opened up another class and used this code I found online and tried to make modifications to get it to work, but it has not been working.

```
import java.util.List;


public class swap {
    //precondition: x and y are >= 0 and < mylist.size()
    //precondition: mylist is not null
    void swap(int x, int y, List <String> myList) {
        String s = myList.get(x);
        myList.add(x, myList.get(y));
        myList.add(y, s);
System.out.println(myList);
} }
```

If I try to replace x and y with position numbers of the elements in the list, then that just causes a host of new problems. As you can probably tell, I'm a beginner to this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're close; `add` isn't the method you're looking for as it inserts rather than replaces. Check the List Javadocs to find the method that replaces, and from there it's a short leap to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ArrayList API, specifically the set() method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)

```
public E set(int index, E element)
```

"Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element."

Give that method a shot instead of add(), probably as follows:

- You can get and store the String from position x (like you're doing),
- Then set the value at position y into position x,
- Finally, set the value at position y from the String you stored earlier.

Basically, whenever you're stuck, it can't hurt to browse the API to see if any of the other methods might make the task a bit easier.  None of us know the API completely by heart, and going back to that doc is a common thing for everyone.  Well, almost everyone.

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is:

1. get the string at x
2. insert string at y, at position x
3. insert previous string at x, at position y

So if you have a list with content `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`, and you called `swap(1, 3, list)`, following the pseudocode, you'd get:

1. `s` becomes "B"
2. list becomes `["A", **"D"**, "B", "C", "D", "E"]`
3. list becomes `["A", "D", "B", **"B"**, "C", "D", "E"]`

What you want to do is swap the values at `x` and `y` by **SETTING** them, not adding them:

```
void swap(int x, int y, List <String> myList) {
    String s = myList.get(x);

    myList.set(x, myList.get(y));
    myList.set(y, s);

    System.out.println(myList);
}
```

This will actually replace the values at index `x` and `y` with each other

Answer (score 0):

You need to use set instead of add.

if you use set it will replace the element in that position with the new element.

```
// arrayList.set(index i,String replaceElement);
```

so your swap function should look like this:

```
public class swap {
    void swap(int x, int y, List <String> myList) {
        String s = myList.get(x);
        myList.set(x, myList.get(y));
        myList.set(y, s);
System.out.println(myList);
} }
```

Comment: He's using he overloaded version of add that also takes an index, so it's not adding to the end of the list.  Unfortunately, he wasn't removing, so the list would just get longer.  Like you've pointed out, set() should handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The Collections.swap(List, int, int) JDK 1.4+ method does just this. Here's an example:

```java
Collections.swap(myList, 0, 1)
```